# Rails Devise update without password with nested attributes keeps rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am working on an update method which override the Devise RegistrationController.

The update_with_password which is simply update passwords for user with a separate form somewhere else works fine. while coming to the update_without_password, the log can see   it keep rollback( logs can see below)

```
Started PUT "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-30 10:45:03 +1000
Processing by RegistrationsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "user"=>{"name"=>"xxxxxx", "email"=>"xxx@gmail.com", "first_name"=>"xxx", "last_name"=>"xxx", "person_attributes"=>{"gender"=>"Unspecified", "description"=>"xxxxxx", "location"=>"xxx", "facebook"=>"https://www.facebook.com/xxxx", "website"=>"", "youtube"=>"", "wikipedia"=>"", "id"=>"11190"}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 11190 LIMIT 1
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 11190]]
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
**Person Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."user_id" = 11190 LIMIT 1**
User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."name" = 'xxxxxx' AND "users"."id" != 11190) LIMIT 1
**(0.3ms)  ROLLBACK**
successfully_updated =======> false
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."user_id" = 11190 LIMIT 1
Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (16.5ms)
```

the Update method is as below:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)

  successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
    @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
  else
    params[:user].delete(:current_password)
    logger.info("USER params ====> #{params[:user]}")

    @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
  end
  logger.info("successfully_updated =======> #{successfully_updated}")  #######  THIS ALWAYS SHOWS "false"
  if successfully_updated
    .
    .(some extra code)
    .
  else
    render "edit"
  end
end
```

I have checked the models, user has the accept_nested_attributes for person; the Person model has all the attr_accessible for this form.

Any idea where i have the problem? I have been trying to find out for a bit of time, but no luck. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check your models setting, like: **accept_nested_attributes** etc, got the same problem before, but really can not remember what i did to fix that.

Comment: what's in your model now?

Comment: Thanks, i think the issue is this **validates :password, :presence => {:message => 'password is required'}**, so the form keep complaint about it, because i need the user to put pass during the signup

Comment: Got the problem solved.  i change the above code into **validates :password, :presence => {:message => 'password is required'}, :on => :create**, so it only checking for create method. Appreciate for all the helpings.